# How can I convert epoch time to date and time in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, time, epoch

I need to convert epoch timestamp to date and time.
I have used the following code to convert but it converts to a wrong date, year and time.

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                    .format(new java.util.Date (1319286637/1000));
```

Expected output was today’s date at some time, but the result I got was:

> 01/01/1970 05:51:59

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Date(long)` constructor takes milliseconds. You should be **multiplying** by 1000, not dividing the epoch time you have.

Answer (score 5):

In brief:

```
Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_319_286_637L )
```

> 2011-10-22T12:30:37Z

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1319286637L);
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-10-22T12:30:37Z
```

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline. The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

You can convert an `Instant` to other Date-Time types e.g.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1319286637);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // A custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtf.format(zdt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-10-22T18:00:37+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
10/22/2011 18:00:37
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note:** The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>. However, for any purpose, if you need to convert this object of `Instant` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>