# Java: epoch date to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, epoch

My time: 1386696238

My code:

```
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(currentNotification.getDate_created()));
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String dateString = formatter.format(date);
```

My result: `1/16/1970`

Desired result: `12/10/2013`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Day in month: `d` (lower case)

Comment: @Reimeus multiplying by 1000 gave me correct dates in my application

Comment: The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7857968/10819573) for an answer using the modern Date-Time API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your value is in seconds, so you need to multiply it by 1000.

Also, `DD` is day of year, you want `dd`:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you should multiply your input with 1000 (UNIX timestamp in seconds, but Java j.u.Date in milliseconds).

Edit:

Oh another mistake in your code: The pattern symbol should be d, not D (day-of-year).