# Convert int to date in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, date, numbers, int

I'm trying to get data from a website, and when I tried to get the date of a post (expected: *13/06/2014 11:55*), i got:

> 23377855

Can someone help me to convert this number to a date? Thanks!

Comment: Sure that's an int? Most likely a long

Comment: Is that in unix time? What have you tried? Without more information, this post is doomed to be closed and deleted in the next couple minutes.

Comment: I really don't know what is this, I just know that site return "13/06/2014 11:55" and my app return "23377855". (URLConnection)

Comment: With no details about that number, we can't help you. If it's a unix timestamp, it's Sep 28/1970, which is probably not correct. If it's a millisecond timestamp, it's even worse 12:29am, Jan 1/1970.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: epoch date to MM/DD/YYYY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326468/java-epoch-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy)

Comment: I don't have any informations about this number =/
I'll try to get it, thanks all for help!

Comment: Fixed, thanks for all. I just multiplied to 60000.

Comment: using SQLite Date Time functions (using DB Browser sqlite) gives me this: 1970-09-28 07:50:55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard Java Date API:

```
        long yourNumber = 23377855;
        Date date = new Date(yourNumber);
```

Or you can use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, provides much better overall functionality than Java Date API:

```
        long yourNumber = 23377855;
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(yourNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is expecting milliseconds:

```
java.util.Date time= new java.util.Date((long)urDateNum*1000);
```

So you must multiply by 1000

Docs say:

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified
>   number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the
>   epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

**Note:**

The cast to `long` is very important in this situation. Without it the `integer` overflows.